# Installing imagemagick on dreamhost VPS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick, carrierwave, dreamhost

I am trying to install imagemagick and rmagick so i can run carrierwave gem with rails. I am on a VPS with dreamhost. Server and installment of gem isn't my forte, i was able to install those gem on my localmachine with the following commands

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick libmagickcore-dev libmagickwand-dev
sudo gem install rmagick
```

But on a VPS server is a bit different, but by doing this it justs not working. What the correct way of installing carrierwave on dreamhost. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have a couple of our wiki articles that may be of some use to you:

http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Image_Magick
http://wiki.dreamhost.com/RMagick

Dreamhost VPS no longer allow admin/sudo users.
<strike>Also, when you're on a VPS, you can only use sudo with an admin user. If you don't already have one set up, you can set one up from your DreamHost panel here: https://panel.dreamhost.com/index.cgi?tree=vserver.adminusers&</strike>

Hope this helps! If not, please don't hesitate to email our support team from your panel. We'll be happy to help, 24 hours a day, 7 days a week. :)

Ellice S

DreamHost Staff